# Is there a performance advantage to buffer a file write before calling fwrite?

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I am working on an image compression codec. The codec has its own stream interface that:

1) performs many small and large writes into single contiguous piece of memory

2) writes contiguous memory to stream interface, which writes to internal buffer, and when buffer is full, does a flush to disk using `fwrite` C interface. Edit: internal buffer size default is 1 MB

Will it improve performance to simply write to disk each time, without intermediate buffers?

The codec is cross platform: windows/osx/linux

Comment: why don't you measure?

Comment: fwrite is already buffered, so probably not.

Comment: @NeilButterworth thanks - this is a very old library that I have inherited - would it have made sense at one point in time to do this buffering in library ?

Comment: Depends on the quantity of data, the multiplicity of threads, presence of DMA hardware and the type of memory.  I found that you can gain some speed by using large buffers in high speed (on chip) memory and DMA.

Comment: When in doubt, **profile**.  All platforms are different.  Your bottlenecks on one platform may be different on another platform.  Also depends on the load placed by other tasks running on the system.  There is the hard disk or SSD overhead to consider as well.

Comment: You are essentially asking about "many small writes to disk" vs "few large writes to disk". And the answer generally depends on your platform (file system implementation + disk driver + actual physical media). From my experience, most of the latency occurs as a result of fragmentation caused by "many small writes", so I would tend to guess that "few large writes" is preferable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks. But, even with large buffers, can I not just set the buffer size that fwrite uses, rather than managing my own buffer? Something tells me to let the low-level file i/o handle the buffering for me.

Comment: I've edited my post: default buffer size for codec internal stream buffer is 1 MB.

Comment: There is an overhead for every transaction and usually constant (for example, the hard drive needs to ramp up its speed before writing).  However, the amount of work to keep the data streaming is negligible (for example, to keep the platters spinning).  Thus, larger buffer sizes can assist in reducing the number of transactions.  The `fwrite` is buffered, but maybe not large enough.  I don't mess with the lower levels, but use my own large buffers.

Comment: Have you looed at `setbuffer`?